# Getting a generic method with reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to get the method `ExecuteQuery` from Azure's `CloudTable`.
There are four methods by this name.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TElement> ExecuteQuery<TElement>(TableQuery<TElement> query, TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null) where TElement : ITableEntity, new();
public virtual IEnumerable<DynamicTableEntity> ExecuteQuery(TableQuery query, TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null);
public virtual IEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteQuery<TElement, TResult>(TableQuery<TElement> query, EntityResolver<TResult> resolver, TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null) where TElement : ITableEntity, new();
public virtual IEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteQuery<TResult>(TableQuery query, EntityResolver<TResult> resolver, TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null);
```

The one I am trying to get is the first one. And I am using the following code.

```
var testQuery = new TableQuery<TestEntity>();
var methodInfo = typeof(CloudTable).GetMethod("ExecuteQuery", new[] { testQuery.GetType(), typeof(TableRequestOptions), typeof(OperationContext) });
```

However methodInfo results in as **null**. Why can't it find the specified method? As I look returning null means there is no such method. By the way TestEntity is a dummy class inheriting from TableEntity and in turn implementing the interface ITableEntity. Therefore the conditions are met for the specified method.

I am going to use this method on a class which is created by reflection at run time. Therefore I am trying to get the method this way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method

Comment: @JonathanAllen In the answer of that question they show how to invoke a generic method once they have it. I know how to invoke it. I am having trouble getting the method. So that answer is not useful in my case.